# Why I need add IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY to access_control in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

The Documentation says :

> Edit the security.yaml file in order to allow access for anyone to the /login route:
>
> ```
>   # config/packages/security.yaml
>   security:
>       # ...
>
>   access_control:
>         - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
>         # ...
> ```

But I don't need to add this, anyone can access URL which is not in access_control, why I need this?

Comment: this is useful if you put the entire application under  `{ path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }` and login is exception... And in case if entire application is fobidden, then you need that line to allow users to login

Answer (score 1):

See This example:

```
 # config/packages/security.yaml
  security:
      # ...

  access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        # ...
```

in this example, the path with `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` roles is only accessed when the user is logged in but in login path, you user can't be login and must be anonymously